# To hide Prototype JS

Tags: prototypejs

```
<ul class="messages">
        <li class="error-msg">
                <ul>
                        <li><span><a href="#item_49" id="ref_wishlist_item_49">"Product6" is available for purchase in increments of 2 only.</a></span></li>
                        <li><span><a href="#item_50" id="ref_wishlist_item_50">"Product3" is available for purchase in increments of 3 only.</a></span></li>
                </ul>
        </li>

</ul>
    <script>
    Event.observe('messages', 'click', function(event) {
        this.remove();
    });

    </script>
```

I want is that when I click on first 'li' which is the children of 'li having class name **error-msg** only this should disappear and when I click on second 'li' then 'ul' having class message should disappear using prototype js.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105495/prototype-show-one-element-hide-siblings

Comment: Also `Event.observe()` takes an id or an element as a parameter, not a class